# Multiple thenApply in a completableFuture

Tags: completable-future

I have a situation where I want to execute some methods in different threads but want to pass the result of one thread to another. I have following methods in my class.

```
public static int addition(int a, int b){
    System.out.println((a+b));
    return (a+b);
}

public static int subtract(int a, int b){
    System.out.println((a-b));
    return (a-b);
}

public static int multiply(int a, int b){
    System.out.println((a*b));
    return (a*b);
}
public static String convert(Integer a){
    System.out.println((a));
    return a.toString();
}
```

here is main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    cf.supplyAsync(() -> addition(a, b))
        .thenApply(r ->subtract(20,r)
                .thenApply(r1 ->multiply(r1, 10))
                .thenApply(r2 ->convert(r2))
                .thenApply(finalResult ->{
                    System.out.println(cf.complete(finalResult));
                }));
    System.out.println(cf.complete("Done"));

}
```

I am trying to pass result of addition to subtraction to multiplication to printing result. But I am getting compilation error. Looks like we can't do nested thenApply(). Is there any way we can do this? Searched it over google and found one helpful link- http://kennethjorgensen.com/blog/2016/introduction-to-completablefutures But didn't find much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong with your snippet:

1. Parenthesis: you have to start the next `thenApply` *after* the end of the one before, not after the `substract` method.
2. `supplyAsync()` is a static method. Use it as such.
3. If you just want to print out the result in the last operation, use `thenAccept` instead of `thenApply`
4. You do not need to complete the CF in `thenAccept` (neither you would have to do it in `thenApply` before.

This piece of code compiles, and it may be close to what you want to achieve:

```
    CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> addition(a, b))
        .thenApply(r -> subtract(20, r))
        .thenApply(r1 -> multiply(r1, 10))
        .thenApply(r2 -> convert(r2))
        .thenAccept(finalResult -> {
            System.out.println("this is the final result: " + finalResult);
        });

    //just to wait until the cf is completed - do not use it on your program
    cf.join();
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben. This works. This is exactly what I was looking for.