# Spring Boot executing parallel methods inside a controller

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to execute some parallel methods inside my controller but i'm having a few problems with the return type.

I have 4 methods and each of those methods return a list.I need to execute those methods in a parallel way and then get each returned list and place all of those lists inside a map and return that map from the controller.
Here's the code:

```
Callable<List> callable1 = new Callable<List>()
           {
              @Override
              public List call() throws Exception
              {
                List<SearchResultAutovit> lista;
                lista = scrapperAutovit.searchAutovit(marcaId, modelId, pretDeLa, pretPanaLa, anFabrDeLa, anFabrPanaLa,
                        orasParam);
                 return lista;
              }
           };

           Callable<List> callable2 = new Callable<List>()
           {
              @Override
              public List call() throws Exception
              {
                  List<SearchResultOlx> listaOlx;
                String marcaOlx = marcaId.toLowerCase();
                String modelOlx = modelId.toLowerCase();
                String orasOlx = orasParam.toLowerCase();
                listaOlx = scrapperOlx.searchOlx(marcaOlx, modelOlx, pretDeLa, pretPanaLa, anFabrDeLa, anFabrPanaLa, orasOlx);
                 return listaOlx;
              }
           };

           Callable<List> callable3 = new Callable<List>()
           {
              @Override
              public List call() throws Exception
              {
                List<SearchResultPubli24> listaPubli24;
                String orasPubli24 = orasParam.toLowerCase();
                listaPubli24 = scrapperPubli24.searchPubli24(marcaId, modelId, orasPubli24, anFabrDeLa, anFabrPanaLa, pretDeLa, pretPanaLa);
                 return listaPubli24;
              }
           };

           Callable<List> callable4 = new Callable<List>()
           {
              @Override
              public List call() throws Exception
              {
                 List<SearchResultAutoUncle> listaAutoUncle;
                listaAutoUncle = scrapperAutoUncle.searchAutoUncle(marcaId, modelId, pretDeLa, pretPanaLa, anFabrDeLa, anFabrPanaLa, orasParam);
                 return listaAutoUncle;
              }
           };

           //add to a list
           List<Callable<List>> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable<List>>();
           taskList.add(callable1);
           taskList.add(callable2);
           taskList.add(callable3);
           taskList.add(callable4);

           ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
           executor.invokeAll(taskList);

           Map<String,List<?>> listOfWebsites = new HashMap<>();
            listOfWebsites.put("listaAutovit", (List<?>) taskList.get(0));
            listOfWebsites.put("listaOlx", (List<?>) taskList.get(1));
            listOfWebsites.put("listaPubli24", (List<?>) taskList.get(2));
            listOfWebsites.put("listaAutoUncle", (List<?>) taskList.get(3));

        return listOfWebsites;
```

I'm pretty sure that i'm not doing something right because it throws `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.controller.HomeController$1 incompatible with java.util.List`
I guess the problem is the map called listOfWebsites which should have the returned type of the callables, some lists:(

Comment: What do you mean? This code is not inside the constructor

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.  I'm in a noisy room.  I'll remove my comment.

Comment: Hint `HomeController$1` is your `Callable`... More generally though, you should plan to do the _whole process_ asynchronously and return a `Future` from your controller method.

Comment: Also - all your lists are rawtypes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change type of callables to avoid casting:

```
    Callable<List<?>> callable1 = new Callable<List>(){...}
```

Then, you have to wait for results of parallel computations. You need not to create `CompletableFuture`s because you can obtain `Future`s directly from `ExecutorService`:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Future<List<?>> future1 = executor.submit(callable1);
    Future<List<?>> future2 = executor.submit(callable2);
    Future<List<?>> future3 = executor.submit(callable3);
    Future<List<?>> future4 = executor.submit(callable4);

    Map<String,List<?>> listOfWebsites = new HashMap<>();
    listOfWebsites.put("listaAutovit", future1.get());
    listOfWebsites.put("listaOlx", future2.get());
    listOfWebsites.put("listaPubli24", future3.get());
    listOfWebsites.put("listaAutoUncle", future4.get());

    return listOfWebsites;
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use completableFuture Object with supplyasync method.
Giving you approach like below:

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> scrapperAutovit.searchAutovit);

CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture1
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> scrapperOlx.searchOlxwith);

CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture2
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> scrapperPubli24.searchPubli24);
```

would be used to check whether you got some response from above call or not.

Like that you can open parallel thread for `scrapperOlx.searchOlxwith` and `scrapperPubli24.searchPubli24` completableFuture object and wait for execution to finish there task and after that consolidate all data and you can process further.

For more details you can refer below link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html
https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-definitive-guide
https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/

This is the good example to understand completablefuture
[Multiple thenApply in a completableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844016/multiple-thenapply-in-a-completablefuture)

Comment: I'm not sure i understand:( where should i use this CompletableFuture?

Comment: all future object which you have created in callable can use by completablefuture like i have mentioned one example for scrapperAutovit.searchAutovit like you can parallel y run with scrapperOlx.searchOlx this as so on i have also shared few link you just go through this link you will understand its a java8 future object.

Comment: Note this will use the common pool rather than a custom executor.

Comment: You can provide the custom executor as well through constructor.public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier,
                                                       Executor executor) {
        return asyncSupplyStage(screenExecutor(executor), supplier);
    }